# What does it mean that the "$(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ are drawn from a product distribution"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

In the book [High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108627771), Wainwright writes:

[image]

*My question:* What exactly is the measure $\mathsf P$ (he uses $\mathbb P$) here and what are the random variables $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ ? As far as I can understand, the $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ are a measurable function from some "un-important" event probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathsf Q)$ to $\mathcal X^n$ and $\mathsf P$ is given as [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) in the following way: $$\mathsf Q= (X_1,\dots,X_n)_* \mathsf P.$$

But then $\mathsf P$ is a measure on $\mathcal X^n$, no? So how could something like $\mathsf P(Z\ge\mathsf E(Z)+\delta)$ be well-defined?

Comment: you are right in the sense that the author is being sloppy with the notation as he/she is mixing the probability measure and the push-forward measure

Answer (score 1):

Each $X_i$ is a random variable on a subset $\mathcal{X}_i \subseteq \mathcal{X}$. "Product distribution" means they are independent random variables.

---

Here I think "$P$" is overloaded as both the measure on the probability space as well as the pushforward. Specifically, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, P)$ is a probability space, and $Z : \Omega \to \mathcal{Z}$ is a random variable, then we often write things like $P(Z \ge \delta)$ to really mean $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : Z(\omega) \ge \delta\})$.

So if you have specified the distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, then your $Z$ is just a function of this random vector, and thus has a probability distribution; this distribution is what the $P$ in $P(Z \ge E[Z] + \delta)$ refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still want to clarify something: I have no issues with the notation $$\mathsf P(Z\geq\delta)=\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega:Z(\omega)\geq\delta\})$$ and I use it all the time. But what Wainwright seems to mean is that $$\mathsf P(Z\geq\delta) =\mathsf Q(\{\omega\in\Omega:Z(\omega)\geq\delta\})$$ (if I understand correctly) as $\mathsf P$ is a measure on $\mathcal X^n$ but $Z$ depends on $\omega$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Sorry I don't quite understand the distinction you are trying to make. Wainwright does not use $Q$ anywhere. You introduced $Q$ as the measure of the underlying probability space. In my answer, I used $P$ instead of your $Q$ for the measure on the probability space, and tried to explain that Wainwright is using $P$ loosely here as both the pushforward and the original measure.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I would not spend too much time worrying about the potential sloppiness of notation here. I don't think the measure-theoretic setup of probability is necessary to understand this section of the book; just think of it as "$X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent."

Comment: Right I see. I am just saying that if you are taking the def. "literally", then $\mathsf P$ seems to be a measure on $\mathcal X^n$ to me and so $\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega:Z(\omega)\geq\delta\})$ is not well-defined. I am a bit petty here because I am writing a text on Talagrand inequalities and one of them is in the chapter mentioned above and I try to have my text be formally correct where I can .